# Deep learning: cannot reshape array in changing MNIST images size

Tags: deep-learning, mnist

I am new on deep learning.I am trying to change mnist images from 28*28 into 224 * 224.

So I decided to use `reshape` method. After importing MNIST data set I try to reshape it:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 224, 224, 1).astype('float32')
```

I am try to change all MNIST image to new size but I got this error:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 224, 224, 1).astype('float32')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-9d12d34bfd75>", line 1, in <module>
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 224, 224, 1).astype('float32')

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 47040000 into shape (60000,224,224,1)
```

How can I change all MNIST image size into new size?

Comment: `reshaping` and `scaling` should be different concepts, reshaping keeps the same number of bytes, scaling is resizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment @datdinhquoc said  **reshaping** keeps the same number of bytes

e.g. if you have array of shape (4,3) , basically there m * n that is 12 (4*3) elements. Now you can reshape it into any size whose multiplication gives you 12. So the array cab be reshaped into size (2,6) or (12,1) .

In your case there are 60,000 elements of size (28, 28), so there are total (60,000 * 28 * 28) and its trying make it (60,000 * 224 * 224), which is obviously impossible.

You want to scale or resize the image. Means you want to increase its bytes. In that case you can use openCV resize function like below

```
 resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
```

So you need to resize all the images one by one.